# Javascript RegEx wont work, but works in c# (atomic subexpression)

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I have a regex tested in Expresso, works like a charm. But when I try to use it in javascript it gave an error.
Firebug says:

```
invalid quantifier ?><div\b[^>]*>(?<DEPTH>)|<\/div>(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))<\/div>
```

the regex:

```
<div\b[^>]*>(?><div\b[^>]*>(?<DEPTH>)|</div>(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))</div>
```

The regex matches nested html-divs such as:

```
<div id="foo"><div>blubb</div><div foobar>blubb</div></div>
```

Is the javascript regex only a subset?

edit:
I have to strip the div's, including the text between them, away.

```
<div id="foo"><div>blubb</div><div foobar>blubb</div></div>some
non html...
```

only the "some non html..." should stay. So I think I can't use any htmlparser?

Comment: For more on what JS supports have a look here http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: In this particular case, JavaScript does not support the "atomic subexpression" syntax `(?>...)`.

Comment: DEPTH is just a named capturing group. Could be replaced with a numbered capturing group. But the problem is the (?>...) like Anon said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the javascript regex only a
>   subset?

No, they are *different* - there are a variety of Regular Expression engines out there, and they each have different features/quirks.

C# is has more features than JavaScript, but JS's one is not derived from C# so it isn't a subset.

Here's a couple of pages that document the differences:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html

And that whole website ([regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)) is well worth browsing to learn more about regex.

> The regex matches nested html-divs

It probably doesn't, not in all cases.

And certainly it wont be possible for a single JS regex, since it doesn't support that depth stuff, amongst other things.

You're using the wrong tool for this job - parsing HTML should be done with a proper HTML parser/selector, then analysing the DOM to find the nested divs.

Anything that implements [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) should do (i.e [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org), and others).

For example, something like `jQuery('div:has(div)')` or `dojo.query('div:has(div)')` or similar, should find nested divs (i.e. select all divs which have a div nested inside them), and will correctly cope with assorted quirks which can be complex if not impossible with a single regex.

> edit: I have to strip the div's, including
>   the text between them, away.
>   `<div id="foo"><div>blubb</div><div foobar>blubb</div></div>some
>   non html...`
>   only the "some non html..." should
>   stay. So I think I can't use any
>   htmlparser?

No - that is even more reason to use a HTML parser, and not attempt a messy regex hack.

```
jQuery('#foo div').remove()
```

That will remove all child DIVs, and leave the HTML text node in place.

Depending on your precise requirements, the selector might need changing, but this is absolutely a task for a tool that is designed to understand HTML.

Comment: I have edited my question, added an example. I think because of that I can't use jQuery. It was my first approach to use it, but it wont work.

Comment: chriszero, I've updated my answer - using jQuery (or equiv) is the right way to handle this. If you're having problems with that approach, I suggest a question specific to that, with details of what/why you're trying to achieve (i.e. provide concise context instead of just some specific details.)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, todays javascript won't support atomic group and recursive regex, but you could easily build a quick&dirty solution by piecewise recursive stripping of tags from html source. If other solutions are too complicated and the structure of the documents is predictable, you could do sth. like:

```
 function stripme(tag, code)
{
 var strp = code;
 var regexp = new RegExp('<'+tag+'[^>]*?>(.*)</'+tag+'>');  // <- involves backtracking 
 while( strp.match(regexp) )            // every level of nesting will lead to
    strp = strp.replace(regexp, '');    // another loop invocation with the captured
 return strp;                           // contents (.*) of the level in RegExp.$1
}                                       // (if needed)
```

This will work with, for example:

```
 var html ='<div id="foo"><div>blubb</div><div foobar>blubb</div></div>some non html...';
```

when invoked with, eg.:

```
 window.onload = function() { var stripped=stripme('div', html); alert(stripped); }
```

BTW, **if possible**, always use a DOM parser or Javascript library as recommended by [Peter Boughton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492912/javascript-regex-wont-work-but-works-in-c/3493005#3493005)

Regards

rbo

Comment: That's very very nice =) I've thought about something similar.

Comment: Instead of "if the structure of the documents is predictable" that part should read "if the structure of the documents is *guaranteed* and there will be no non-removable text between removed tags" - i.e. if the input was `<div><div>stuff</div></div>don't remove<div>stuff</div>` the whole of that would be removed.

Comment: Passing in `b` will incorrectly remove `blockquote`, so you need a `\s` before the `[^>]*?` to prevent that - oh and you've got an unnecessary non-greedy quantifier - with `[^>]*?>` it'll always keep going until the next char is a `>` anyway, so can just use `[^>]*>` instead (with regex that supports atomic, there might be a speed improvement for non-matches with a possessive quantifier `[^>]*+>`, but if so it'd be minor)

Comment: One more thought - depending on the source, it might be worth making the regex case-insensitive; potentially there are div/DIV mismatches to deal with.

Comment: Peter - you can't handle nested stuff in Javascript-regex flavor, this would require recursiveness or at least code assertions (like Perl) for support of counting. If there are simple cases (like in the original posting and of compareable structure) one would possibly use a hand-crafted (for this special use case) solution. In any other case one would of course use the right tool for the job. Thanks & Regards, rbo